# Beautifulsoup results to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

The below code returns me a `table` with the following results

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

mylist = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'table_grey_border'})
print(mylist)
```

**results - it stretches on for 1700 rows**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="table_grey_border" width="100%">
<tr valign="top">
<td class="verd_black12" width="18%"><b>STOCK CODE</b></td>
<td class="verd_black12" width="42%"><b>NAME OF LISTED SECURITIES</b></td>
<td class="verd_black12" width="19%"><b>BOARD LOT</b></td>
<td class="verd_black12" colspan="4" width="12%"><b>REMARK</b></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_normal">
<td class="verd_black12" width="18%">00001</td>
<td class="verd_black12" width="42%"><a href="../../../invest/company/profile_page_e.asp?WidCoID=00001&amp;WidCoAbbName=&amp;Month=&amp;langcode=e" target="_parent">CKH HOLDINGS</a></td>
<td class="verd_black12" width="19%">500</td>
<td align="center" class="verd_black12" width="3%">#</td>
<td align="center" class="verd_black12" width="3%">H</td>
<td align="center" class="verd_black12" width="3%">O</td>
<td align="center" class="verd_black12" width="3%">F</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_normal">
<td class="verd_black12" width="18%">00002</td>
<td class="verd_black12" width="42%"><a href="../../../invest/company/profile_page_e.asp?WidCoID=00002&amp;WidCoAbbName=&amp;Month=&amp;langcode=e" target="_parent">CLP HOLDINGS</a></td>
<td class="verd_black12" width="19%">500</td>
<td align="center" class="verd_black12" width="3%">#</td>
<td align="center" class="verd_black12" width="3%">H</td>
<td align="center" class="verd_black12" width="3%">O</td>
<td align="center" class="verd_black12" width="3%">F</td>
</tr>
...
```

My question is, how do I put each of these rows into Pandas Dataframe? I tried the below code, but i'm returned with an error

```
a = pandas.read_html(mylist)
print(a)
```

**error**

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: always put FULL error message. There are other usefull information. I tried `read_html` with your HTML and it works without error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

```
pandas.read_html(url, attrs={'class': 'table_grey_border'})
```